# audio power on AudioQueue

Tags: cocoa, core-audio

I'm now creating an Application using speech recognition.To check the Audio Power coming in through the microphone,
I wrote a method as follows.

```
-(void)checkPower(AudioqueRef)queue{
   UInt32 expectedSize= sizeof(AudioQueueLevelMeterState);
   AudioQueueGetProperty(queue,
                     kAudioQueueProperty_CurrentLevelMeter,
                     audioLevels,          
                        expectedSize);
   NSLog(@"average:%f peak:%f",audioLevels.mAveragePower,audioLevels.mPeakPower);
}
```

I found that sometimes mAveragePower was larger than mPeakPower,
and when mAveragePower was 1.0, in other words, averagePower
is regarded as max, mPeakPower was lower than 1.0.

I think that generally this result is inpossible.
please Let me know if you have any information about sound power on CoreAudio.

thanks.

Comment: are you checking the result code (OSStatus) returned by AudioQueueGetProperty? On error, the values are likely to not make sense.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.I checked OSStatus, but It was"noErr"...

Answer (score 0):

I think mPeakPower means channel power at CURRENT moment & mAveragePower - average channel power for ALL record time, and if it's right your result possible.